# SQL Logic Help Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working in SQL Server 2012 with Reporting Services to build a query that gives me a list of member who used a service off of their account in period one but that did not use a service on their account in period two.

The tables I am working with are:

- MEMBERS (List of Members)
- SS (List of the services on a member's account)
- SSUSED: Keeps a record of the services used (some services can be 1 of 1, 3 of 3 or 6 of 6)
- PRODUCTS - List of products
- PRODUCTCATS - Product Categories

I have built the following query that gives me a list of members that used a product off of their accounts for a specific period of time, but I am having issues filtering out people that used a product in the second period.

The members table gives me the unique member identifier of memid, SS gives me a table of the service on the members account linked by memid, SSUSED keeps a history of the services used, products gives me the products on the SS table and the PRODUCTCATS is a table that lists the product categories for the PRODUCTS table. PRODUCTS are linked to PRODUCTCATS with productid, MEMBERS are linked to SS with memid and SS is linked to SSUSED with ssid.

```
SELECT     
    MEMBERS.memid
FROM            
    SS 
INNER JOIN
    SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid 
INNER JOIN
    MEMBERS ON SS.memid = MEMBERS.memid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid
WHERE        
    (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) 
    AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like following:

```
With cte1 as
(
Select * from tables where period = period1
)
,cte2 as
(
Select * from tables where period = period2
)
Select * from cte1 a
Left join cte2 b on 
A... = b...
Where b.period is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a count for the times a member record appears in period1 and period2 and check that.

```
SELECT   *
FROM
(
    SELECT MEMBERS.memid,
           COUNT(CASE
                     WHEN usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1
                     THEN 1
                 END) Period1Count,
           COUNT(CASE
                     WHEN usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2
                     THEN 1
                 END) Period2Count
    FROM   SS
           INNER JOIN SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid
           INNER JOIN MEMBERS ON SS.memid = MEMBERS.memid
           INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid
           INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid
    WHERE  (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN(27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68))
           AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
    GROUP BY MEMBERS.memid
) t
WHERE t.Period1Count > 0 AND t.Period2Count  = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So members (`MEMBERS`) and services used (`SSUSED`) are n:m related, for which you have a bridge table `SS`. You'd join members and services via this table and aggregate per member. Count entries in both periods:

```
select m.memid
from members m
join ss on ss.memid = m.memid
join ssused s on s.ssid = ss.ssid
where m.siteid = @rvSite
and ss.productid in
(
  select pc.productid
  from productcats pc
  where pc.productcatid in (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68)
)
group by m.memid
having count(case when s.usedate between @rvStartWeek1 and @rvEndWeek1 then 1 end) > 1
   and count(case when s.usedate between @rvStartWeek2 and @rvEndWeek2 then 1 end) = 0;
```